Splitting up query with join, using load in strict mode
I wrote a code something like this:
$bunnies = Bunny::with(['carrots' => function ($query) use ($request){
    if (empty($request->carrotStatus))
        return;
    $query->where('status', $request->carrotStatus);
}, 'owner'])
->select('bunnies.*')
->join('carrots', 'bunnies.id', '=', 'carrots.bunny_id')
->where(function (Builder $query) use ($request){
    if (empty($request->carrotStatus))
        return;
    $query->where('carrots.status', $request->carrotStatus);
})
->where(function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
    if (empty($request->multiSearch)) {
        return;
    }
    $query
        ->orWhereLike('carrots.name', "%{$request->multiSearch}%")
        ->orWhereLike('bunnies.name', "%{$request->multiSearch}%");
})
->groupBy('bunnies.id')
->orderBy('bunnies.id', 'asc')
->paginate(
    perPage: $request->get('pageSize', 5),
    page: $request->get('page', 1)
);

It runs in strict mode. https://laravel-news.com/shouldbestrict
I wonder if it is possible to make it less ugly. I don't like that I give the bunny type twice Bunny:: and ->select('bunnies.*') and that I use table names instead of model names only. I don't like the with part, but I am not sure if it is possible to replace it to load in strict mode. Can somebody help with these two?

you can break the query into smaller parts (i will post an answer soon unfortunately i have a 30min wait time between posts :(

I managed to solve this:
$bunnies = Project::whereHas('carrots', function ($query) use ($request){
    if (!empty($request->carrotStatus))
        $query->where('carrots.status', $request->carrotStatus);
    if (!empty($request->multiSearch))
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->whereLike('carrots.name', "%{$request->multiSearch}%")
            ->orWhereLike('bunnies.name', "%{$request->multiSearch}%");
        });
})
->orderBy('bunnies.id', 'asc')
->paginate(
    perPage: $request->get('pageSize', 5),
    page: $request->get('page', 1)
);

if (empty($request->carrotStatus))
    $bunnies->load('carrots');
else
    $bunnies->load(['carrots' => function ($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('status', $request->carrotStatus);
    }]);
$bunnies->load('owner');

I replaced the with to load, so I was able to separate the eager loading part from the query. After it I moved the !empty conditions outside the closures. And finally I changed the ugly select-join to whereHas which is in theory somewhat faster too. I was not able to use model names only, but it is not a real issue since I carrots is not a table name, but the relationship name here.

This looks pretty good, but some notes; you should still be able to use ->with() instead of ->load() (->load() is typically used when your Model(s) are queried "elsewhere", ->with() is used when you're doing the querying), and there's also the ->when() clause that could encapsulate your if(empty(...)) conditional (->when(condition, true callback, optional false callback)). There's also ->withWhereHas() that filters and loads a relationship that you might be able to use (if needed). This is a good improvement though

@TimLewis Thanks! I'll try to improve it further with your suggestions. I like the load better because it is easier to understand it this way and break it up into multiple lines.

For sure! I only suggest the ->when() clause as you'd be able to do ->when(empty(...), function ($query) { $query->with('carrots'); }, function ($query) { $query->with('carrots', function ($subQuery) { $query->where(...); }})->orderBy(...)->paginate(...), which you wouldn't be able to do with ->load() (since you need to have the Models loaded before). But if you wanted to split that logic, then your approach as-is works for that. It's nice that Laravel offers a lot of flexibility with syntax, and ultimately what works best is up to you. Cheers

you can break the query into multiple parts like this :
$query = Bunny::with(['carrots' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    if (!empty($request->carrotStatus)) {
        $query->where('status', $request->carrotStatus);
    }
}, 'owner'])
->select('bunnies.*')
->join('carrots', 'bunnies.id', '=', 'carrots.bunny_id');

if (!empty($request->carrotStatus)) {
    $query->where('carrots.status', $request->carrotStatus);
}

if (!empty($request->multiSearch)) {
    $query->where(function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('carrots.name', 'like', "%{$request->multiSearch}%")
              ->orWhere('bunnies.name', 'like', "%{$request->multiSearch}%");
    });
}

$bunnies = $query->groupBy('bunnies.id')
    ->orderBy('bunnies.id', 'asc')
    ->paginate(
        perPage: $request->get('pageSize', 5),
        page: $request->get('page', 1)
    );


also you can use if(!condition) { what you wanna do } instead of if(condition) return then what you want to do under it :)

It is an improvement, but I want to get rid of mixing eloquent and plain SQL queries somehow if possible. If not, then I can accept your answer. I was wondering whether it is possible to make this with load instead of with, but probably not, because strict mode.
